# Why does score for mysql boolean match give different score?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, pattern-matching

I am attempting to use MySQL's fulltext search using Boolean match on multiple columns, with multiple search phrases. I cannot understand the score returned though. The score returned is typically an integer, but occasionally returns a float, particularly when using optional statements. The table in question is MyISAM.

Example:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(columna,columnb,columnc) 
AGAINST('+"exact phrase" +definitely -negative this that) as score 
FROM table 
WHERE MATCH(columna,columnb,columnc) 
AGAINST('+"exact phrase" +definitely -negative maybe) >= score
```

In the above statement I'm searching for `exact phrase`, `definitely`, not `negative`, and `this` or `that`.

When performing the query we get a varying score depending on the number of search terms used and the operator(and,or,not) being used for each item.

Comment: Do not trust the values of `MATCH`.  They are only _generally_ relevant.